# Encrypted fields creation limit

Tags: encryption

Can someone please let me know, if there any limit for number of encrypted fields allowed per object or per per org?

Answer (score 1):

It seems Encrypted fields numbers counted according to your Salesforce Edition. We have number of field types in Salesforce but we don't find number of fields limitation for per object or ORG except the following fields.

[image]

So if a Salesforce edition has 500 fields limitation per object then it will be counted in 500 fields.

Answer (score 0):

As a word of warning I could not find a confirmation from SF in their docs for a set limit of encrypted fields, but I believe they are simply treated as a custom field.

So in theory I think you can have the same number of encrypted fields as custom fields (see the [limits cheatsheet](https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf) for custom field limits per org type). There are also limitations on encrypted fields (check out [SF Help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm&language=en_US)).